# How to write subquery IN conditional zend 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have MySQL Query i want to write this query zend 2.

```
select billsec, call_status, Count(*) 
from (
    select
        billsec,
        if(ANSWERED_NUM is Null, 'Missed', 'Answered') call_status
    from cust_info 
    where billsec in (
        select id 
        from `users` 
        where `account_id` = 452 and `added_by` = 20694 and `status` = 'active'
    )
)a 
group by a.billsec,a.call_status
```

in zend 2 am trying to write like this but

```
$adapter   = $this->getAdapter();
    $resultset = $this->select( function( Select $select ) use ( $request, $adapter ) {
        $sub1  = new Select( 'users' );
        $sub1->columns( array( 'id'  ) );
        $sub1->where( array( 'account_id' => '452','added_by' => '20694','status' => 'active' ) );
            
        $sub2   = new Select( 'cust_info' );
        $sub2->columns(array("id","billsec", "if(ANSWERED_NUM is Null, 'Missed','Answered')"=>"call_status"));
        $sub2->where('billsec IN(?)', new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression( '?', array( $sub1 ) ));
       

        var_dump( $sub2->getSqlString( $adapter->getPlatform() ) );die();
    });
```

When am print this query output like this:

```
"SELECT `cust_info`.`id` AS `id`, `cust_info`.`billsec` AS `billsec`, `cust_info`.`call_status` AS `if(ANSWERED_NUM is Null, 'Missed','Answered')` FROM `cust_info` WHERE billsec IN('')"
```

Here am not able to write IN condition Query, thank in advance.

Comment: `new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression($sub1->getSqlString()))` should do the trick

Comment: This trick is not working its show same sql query.